# Tile mapping error

Tags: c++, mapping, sfml, tile

I am still learning SFML and C++ so please understand that I'm still at the basic level.
This is my first time using this site so IDK if I'm doing this right. 
I want to make a function, `set`, that will allow me to pass a 2d array as an argument and place a tile down whenever there is a 1 in the array. So I can draw maps and things using a matrix. ww is the window width and wh is the window height. In `main` I made a for loop that would go through tiles and draw them to the window. But when I run this it gives me the error: Segmentation Fault (core dumped) "Error: 139". Is there a better way of doing this and what am I doing wrong?
Thank you.

```
struct field
{
    int rectsizex;
    int rectsizey;
    RectangleShape * tiles;

    field (int s)
    {
        rectsizex = ww / s;
        rectsizey = wh / s;

        tiles = new RectangleShape[rectsizex * rectsizey];
    }
    ~field()
    {
        delete tiles;
    }

    RectangleShape * set(int ** matr)
    {
        Vector2f size((ww / rectsizex), (wh / rectsizey));      
        int posx = ww / rectsizex;
        int posy = wh / rectsizey;

        for(int x = 0; x<rectsizex; x++)
        {
            for(int y = 0; y<rectsizey; y++)
            {
                int i = ((x*rectsizey)+1)+y;
                tiles[i].setSize(size);
                if(matr[x][y] == 1)
                {
                    tiles[i].setFillColor(Color::Black);
                }
                else
                {
                    tiles[i].setFillColor(Color::White);
                }
                tiles[i].setPosition(x * posx, y * posy);   
            }
        }

        return tiles;   
    }



};
```

Comment: This is a basic programming problem, best solved by using a debugger. You will encounter many of those problems and you need the right tool. Check your development tools and learn how to use the debugger of the IDE you use.

Answer (score 0):

Find out what values you are getting for i:

```
int i = ((x*rectsizey)+1)+y;
```

This value is definitely outside of your array bounds, hence the error.  Use a debugger, or put some print statements after you get the i value.